# How to create role column with laravel livewire tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to create a table using [laravel livewire tables](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-livewire-tables). I managed to create all other columns except the Roles one.

I'm using Laravel 10, Jetstream and livewire.

Here is my code:

```
protected $model = User::class;

    public function configure(): void
    {
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
    }

    public function columns(): array
    {
        return [
            Column::make("Name", "name")
                ->sortable(),
            Column::make("Email", "email")
                ->sortable(),
            Column::make("Role", "role.name") // The problem is here. I get this error Too few arguments to function App\Models\User::scopeRole(), 1 passed in
                ->sortable(),
            Column::make("Team", "currentTeam.name")
                ->sortable(),
            Column::make("Created at", "created_at")
                ->sortable(),
        ];
    }

    public function builder(): Builder
    {
        return User::query()
            ->with('roles')
            ->with('teams')
            ->when($this->columnSearch['name'] ?? null, fn($query, $name) => $query->where('users.name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%'))
            ->when($this->columnSearch['email'] ?? null, fn($query, $email) => $query->where('users.email', 'like', '%' . $email . '%'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have livewire installed. run this command.

```
php artisan make:livewire UsersTable
```

This command will generate a new Livewire component file called UsersTable.php in the app/Http/Livewire directory.

Define the properties and render method
Open the `UsersTable.php` file and define the necessary properties and the render method. The render method is responsible for rendering the component's view.

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class UsersTable extends Component
{
  public $users;

  public function mount()
  {
    $this->users = User::all();
  }

  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.users-table');
  }
}
```

Create the Livewire view
Create a new Livewire view file called `users-table.blade.php` in the `resources/views/livewire` directory.

```php
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->role }}</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Use the Livewire component in your Blade template
To use the Livewire component in your Blade template, include the `livewire:users-table` directive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Your head content -->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Your body content -->
    
  <livewire:users-table />
    
  @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

That's it! You now have a Livewire table component with a role column. When you load the page, the Livewire component will fetch the users from the database and render the table with the appropriate data.